# Springboot application to export data to csv file using Open CSV

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, opencsv

I want to export data to csv file for which I have done the following:
Bean class:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Integer id;
    private String phone;

   getters and setters...
}
```

My pom file has required dependency (just showing the required libraries)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I created an API with the following code, my requirement is to have a post mapping as I will be passing parameters from the application on basis of which the data will be formed.

```
@PostMapping("csv")
    public ResponseEntity csv() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {

        List<MyObject> myObjects = createSampleList();

        Map<String, String> columnMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        columnMap.put("id", "Id");
        columnMap.put("name", "User Name");
        columnMap.put("email", "User Email");
        columnMap.put("phone", "User Phone");

        List<String[]> csvData = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] header = columnMap.values().toArray(String[]::new);

        csvData.add(header);

        for (MyObject myObject : myObjects) {
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String key : columnMap.keySet()) {
                Field field = MyObject.class.getDeclaredField(key);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                String value = String.valueOf(field.get(myObject));
                row.add(value);
            }
            csvData.add(row.toArray(String[]::new));
        }

        return (ResponseEntity) ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + "Mohit")
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv")).body(csvData);

    }

private static List<MyObject> createSampleList() {
        List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        MyObject myObject1 = new MyObject();
        myObject1.setId(1);
        myObject1.setName("Name 1");
        myObject1.setEmail("Email 1");
        myObject1.setPhone("111-121-2121");

        MyObject myObject2 = new MyObject();
        myObject2.setId(2);
        myObject2.setName("Name 2");
        myObject2.setEmail("Email 2");
        myObject2.setPhone("111-121-2121");

        MyObject myObject3 = new MyObject();
        myObject3.setId(3);
        myObject3.setName("Name 3");
        myObject3.setEmail("Email 3");
        myObject3.setPhone("111-121-2121");

        myObjects.add(myObject1);
        myObjects.add(myObject2);
        myObjects.add(myObject3);

        return myObjects;
    }
```

With the above code I keep getting an error

```
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.ArrayList] with preset Content-Type 'text/csv']
```

So I tried using Open CSV library but I see it only works with a get request and with the below code the file is always empty

```
@GetMapping("csv1")
    public void csv1(HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException, NoSuchFieldException,
            SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        List<MyObject> myObjects = createSampleList();

        Map<String, String> columnMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        columnMap.put("id", "Id");
        columnMap.put("name", "User Name");
        columnMap.put("email", "User Email");
        columnMap.put("phone", "User Phone");

        List<String[]> csvData = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] header = columnMap.values().toArray(String[]::new);

        csvData.add(header);

        for (MyObject myObject : myObjects) {
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String key : columnMap.keySet()) {
                Field field = MyObject.class.getDeclaredField(key);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                String value = String.valueOf(field.get(myObject));
                row.add(value);
            }
            csvData.add(row.toArray(String[]::new));
        }

        String fileName = "Employee1.csv";

        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        StatefulBeanToCsv<String[]> writer1 = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<String[]>(response.getWriter())
                .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER).withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR).build();

        writer1.write(csvData);
    }
```

How can I achieve this with a post method and allow user to download the csv file over the browser?